# Selenium - $(dollar sign) getting replaced $$(double dollar sign)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium.

we have one test suit.In this we are reading variables data from XML file.

Issue is if variable has dollar($) sign in value then its getting replaced with double dollar($$)

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to elaborate your question. There are many possibilities. Kindly debug the code. If you filling up text box value, make sure that you clear() your text box before doing sendkey().